# Preload dynamically filtered has_many association with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to include / preload a has_many association that has a dynamic runtime condition. I'm getting the correct result, but my variable is hard coded and I'm not sure how to pass it from includes.

**My query:**

```
@volunteers = Volunteer.includes({ signups: [{position: [{ eventday: :event }] }] }, :event_survey_results).where(events: { id:  @event.id })
```

**Volunteer model:**

```
class Volunteer < ApplicationRecord
  # Hard coded solution works
  has_many :event_survey_results, -> { where event_id: 60 }, class_name: 'Questionnaires::SurveyResult'
end
  # Dynamic solution. How to pass event_id to this from :includes ?
  has_many :event_survey_results, ->(event_id) { where event_id: event_id }, class_name: 'Questionnaires::SurveyResult'
end
```

I need to pass event_id to event_survey_results has_many dynamic solution in the :includes statement. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Rails 5.1

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` doesn't have such feature as it can be done using a standard where clause as per Rails Team, check please :

**There is no need to add this functionality. It's already there using standard where clauses**
**Reference:**
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3912

You can do the following:

**Edited query:**

```
# @event.id refers to the value of 60
@volunteers = Volunteer.includes({ signups: [{position: [{ eventday: :event }] }] }, :event_survey_result).where(event_survey_results: { id:  @event.id })
```

**Volunteer model:**

```
class Volunteer < ApplicationRecord
  # No need to filter here, as you can filter it using standard where
  has_many :event_survey_results , class_name: 'Questionnaires::SurveyResult'

end
```

Comment: I tried that already, but if the volunteer does not have an event_survey_result he is not included in @volunteers. This is supposed to be a left join, but it is not acting like it.

Comment: Here is the article I was reading explaining the problem. Towards the end it explains the issue with the left join excluding records from the left table if they are missing on the right table. https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/conditional-eager-loading-in-rails-9b1c1c592897